# Django Content reserved word?

Tags: python, django

getting this error when trying to import my model...

```
from pages.models import Content
ImportError: cannot import name Content
```

The reason why it's strange is because it's 100% there!!!! I have done this many times. Is there something wrong with the name 'Content' it is a reserved word?

Content is in my model and my model is 100 in pages.models!!!

Comment: did you register your pages app?

Comment: @dm03514 register in terms of INSTALLED_APPS yes it's in my installed applications.

Comment: does your `pages` app have an `__init__.py` ?

Comment: Is this traceback full?

Comment: ps, I can import any of my other models from my others apps, just not this one

Comment: @karthikr  yes both have the init files

Comment: do you have a model named `Content` in your `pages/models.py`? Do you have other classes in your `pages/models.py` that can be imported successfully?

Comment: @soon full stack posted

Comment: clearly, the error is not in `Content`. Check in all the models that you are importing from

Comment: ok the error is at this link when importing inside models from shorturl.models import Link maybe something wrong with this app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have circular dependent imports. In `pages.models` file you tries to import `shorturl.models.Link`, but at the same time in `shorturl.models` you tries to import `Content` from `pages.models`.

Comment: dam yes I do!!! I need content as a fk and import link for the content on save tho, dam it.

Comment: or, you can just import right before the call in one of the 2 places.